# Installing textext-0.4.4 in Inkscape 0.91

Tags: latex, extension, inkscape

I am trying to install textext-0.4.4 in Inkscape 0.91.
I am on Ubuntu 15.04.

I follow the same procedure for Ubuntu 14.04, but it does not work.

1. Install Pstoedit and pdflatex
2. download textext-0.4.4.
3. move `LICENSE.txt`, `textext.inx`, `textext.py` in `~/.config/inkscape/extensions/`
4. start inkscape

Unfortunately, under extensions I do not see Tex Text.

Output from `ls -la ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/`

```
total 96
drwxr-x--x 2 werty werty  4096 Jul 10 20:28 .
drwxr-x--x 7 werty werty  4096 Jul 10 12:46 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root   root    1522 Jul 10 13:01 LICENSE.txt
-rw------- 1 root   root     415 Jul 10 13:01 textext.inx
-rwxr-x--- 1 root   root   32240 Jul 10 20:28 textext.py
-rwxr-x--- 1 root   root   45867 Jul 10 20:28 textext.py~
```

Output from `sudo ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/textext.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oftefs/.config/inkscape/extensions/textext.py", line 933, in <module>
    e.affect()
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex.py", line 262, in affect
self.svg_file = args[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Works great here. [Edit] your question and post the output of `ls -la ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/` and the output of `~/.config/inkscape/extensions/textext.py`. There should be an error message like `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Do you have 15.04 ?

Comment: Yes 15.04, um, let me check my inkscape version

Comment: Inkscape is `0.91-3ubuntu1`

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy inkscape`

Comment: I found the error. Read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The extension was accessible only by `root`. Correct this access rights via

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/*
```